# Detect invalid certificate for WebSocket

Tags: javascript, websocket, detection, certificate-authority

Is it possible to detect that a secure websocket was closed because of an invalid certificate?

If so, how?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, it is not possible.

The client will close with 1006 code:

> 1006
>
> ```
>   1006 is a reserved value and MUST NOT be set as a status code in a
>   Close control frame by an endpoint.  It is designated for use in
>   applications expecting a status code to indicate that the
>   connection was closed abnormally, e.g., without sending or
>   receiving a Close control frame.
> ```

Also, the `onerror` handler will be called, but it says nothing about the certificate or other particular problem.

https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc6455#section-7.4

Comment: This is very strange.  Why is so much side functionality being denied websockets?  Can't get IP either even though one can with ajax.

Comment: Yes, I was also surprised. You cannot add custom headers or send pings neither.